# Can I modify HTML elements' properties in parallel?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Imagining that I have to apply same inline styles to 1000+ HTML elements, if I using a simple for-loop, I have to setting the `style` property for 1000+ times. But since setting style to any DOM element are independent to each other, there must be faster if I can do it in parallel. For example, I can create 4 Web Workers first, and tell each Worker to process one fourth amount of elements, which may take advantage of multicore and hence improve performance significancely. But sadly I've heard that Web Worker didn't support changing DOM. Are there some other method that can achieve my goal?

Comment: Wouldn't adding class and setting style for that would be an easier option?

Comment: No. the style is determined by the user. The user select elements he want to change and set the styles by clicking toolbars button. The combination of style is various and unperdictable. Imagining this is a Rich Text System.

Comment: Processing the DOM in web workers is slower than processing the DOM in the main thread. jQuery tried this and benchmarked it. React does it differently, modifying internal React objects in web workers then updating the DOM in the main thread. The fastest most optimal way to do this is to NOT DO IT IN PARALLEL

Comment: Have you benchmarked your requiremnts? 1000 style changes is a very small amount and not even noticeable. The key is to avoid reflow - that is, DO NOT read new calculated values like width/height in the middle of changing all those 1000 styles. Read them before or after changing all the styles. That's how React does it. Reflow slows you down. Changing styles do not trigger computation until the next reflow

Comment: @slebetman gotcha.